# How do I add G1GC parameter in JBOSS EAP 7.1.0?

Tags: jboss

We are using JBOSS EAP7.1.0 module and have written puppet module for the same . We have separated the hiera and code .The  max and min heap size is added as below :

```
wildfly::java_xmx:        '2048m'
wildfly::java_xms:        '2048m'
```

Can anyone tell me how can I add -XX:+UseG1GC,  [Garbage Collector --> G1] and -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError ?

Comment: do you need to use puppet for those settings? 
if not you can always edit the standalone.conf/standalone.conf.bat (depending on whether your jboss runs on windows or linux and add  -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to the JAVA_OPTS

Comment: I need to add this in the yaml file of the hiera code (Puppet)

Comment: can you try this: 
wildfy::java_opts: '-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'

unfortunately i have not worked with puppet myself, but i have found an example file here: https://github.com/erwbgy/puppet-tomcat/blob/master/example.yaml which suggests that this might be the solution to your problem. 

please let me know if it works

Comment: cool! it would be amazing if you could accept/upvote the answer. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wildfy::java_opts: '-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'

Comment: After I add G1GC with the command  - wildfly::java_opts:'-XX:+UseG1GC' I am unable to add new options  example :  wildfly::gc_logs: '-Xloggc:/opt/jboss-eap/gc_logs/jvm-gc.log  -XX:+PrintGCDetails   -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps'. When the new line is added the old one is removed.The output is as below:

Comment: if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xloggc:/opt/jboss-eap/gc_logs/jvm-gc.log  -XX:+PrintGCDetails   -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"   here  '-XX:+UseG1GC'  is removed...can anyone help?

Comment: Try the following and let me know if it works: 

wildfly::java_opts: ''-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xloggc:/opt/jboss-eap/gc_logs/jvm-gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps'

this should use all your java_opts and set them at once, so nothing should get overriden.